# How to replace the text in jquery loop

Tags: jquery

I need to replace `*****` with `;` for which I had modified my below code. However it's not working. Can anybody help me out?

```js
function show_records(data) {
  let html = "";
  $.each(data, function(k, v){
    var CustDataValue = new URL(v.url); 
    console.log(url.hostname);
    html += `<input type="radio" name="${url.hostname}" /> ${ url.hostname }<br />`
  })
  html+='</div></div>'
  $('.editviewm').append(html);

}
```

Comment: What is the exact value in `v.CstDataValue`? Is it already HTML encoded?

Comment: yes we are getting values in different lengths

Comment: string.replace(/ØæŒ/g,';');